# div moving out of position once I remove this div

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why when I remove line#45:

```
<div class="headerBreak"></div>
```

The header shifts down the page.

This is also my first attempt writing one of these webpages so please excuse the messiness. Still going through a lot of trial and error.

- https://jsfiddle.net/6fr1azhp/

Can anyone explain whats going on?

Comment: @the12 he clearly states that if he removes `<div class="headerBreak"></div>` , which I can perfectly reproduce on any browser setup, the page moves down a bit.

Comment: FYI, you shouldn't have html structure elements in your `<head>` tag. That should all be contained in the `<body>`.

Comment: @Derek Story I will move the html elements into the body, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add top: 0; to .header.
If you are setting element as fixed, remember to specify his position.

Comment: Thanks, that did it